# Perl - increment value within ternary operator

Tags: perl, increment, ternary-operator

I am simply trying to increment a value within the ternary operator's 'true' section when the `test()` subroutine returns true, but set it back to zero when the it returns false.

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $int = 5;

test() ? $int += 1 : $int = 0;

print "$int\n"; # => prints "0"

sub test {
  return 1; #return true
}
```

Comment: `test()` is not a method, it is a subroutine.

Comment: I fixed the ambiguity for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple: perl's [ternary operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) is assignable

In particular, your code really means this:

```
(test() ? $int += 1 : $int) = 0;
```

You may recall that the result of an assignment is the variable being assigned to; this means that the following happens:

1. test() evaluates to true
2. $int += 1 is evaluated, incrementing $int to 6
3. The result of the assignment, $int, is assigned the value 0

This code will work how you want:

```
test() ? ($int++) : ($int = 0);
```

Or this:

```
$int += test() ? 1 : -$int; #If you want to be cute
```

Comment: I see. I had a feeling it was a very simple answer, but after researching I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest making perldoc your first resort; it really is a beautifully comprehensive set of documentation.